# Finding pseudoprimes using differences of prime products

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-numbers

> Using the first nine primes $(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23)$, what is the smallest (2nd smallest if $1$ is possible) difference that can be created using products of these primes?
>
> Rules are as follows: you must use all nine primes with each prime on only one side of the subtraction sign, squares and higher powers of those primes are allowed, positive answers only (absolute value of difference).

For instance: the best I've found is $2^2\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 23-3\cdot 5\cdot 17\cdot 19^2=37$. Obviously 2-28 are impossible.

I suspect that $29$ and $31$ are possible but have not found ways to get them or prove they exist.

Comment: Question is getting old and no answers...

Comment: Maybe 29 and 31 are impossible? Anyone game for proving it?

Comment: all your examples of differences are prime numbers, so it is a little confusing: are you looking for "the smallest difference" or the "smallest prime difference"? According to the examples it seems you are focused only on primes, but according to the description it would be any natural number, not only primes. Just in case.

Comment: @iadvd By the very nature of these differences, they cannot have any prime factors less than $29$. Thus, the smallest composite difference possible should be $29^2$. It would be interesting to see if this is possible. But either way, some knowledge of modular arithmetic shows that any difference from $29$ to $29^2$ thus created will be prime.